# Will `nodetool repair` also repair against machines holding data they don't own in ring?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Let's say I have a cluster of three nodes with (for simplicity) a replication factor of 1. Let's call the nodes A, B and C.

According to the ring, the partition key X should be stored on A. However, due to a database recovery, the data for partition key X has ended up on node B (and A doesn't store X at all).

Question: If I issue `nodetool repair`, will it make sure that partition key X ends up on A?

I understand, that the real way of doing the database recovery would be to use something like `sstableloader`, however due to unforeseen circumstances doing the above might be an easier solution for me (if it works!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use repairs for clusters with replication factor 1. It just doesn't make sense for Cassandra to repair data across nodes if each node exclusively owns his own token range. Using `sstableloader` would be the cleaner solution in this case.

Comment: I see. So a repair doesn't check for data against every other node?

Comment: It does and it does not. Allow me to point you to https://cassandra-zone.com/understanding-repairs/#what-should-be-repaired:523f18cb3f40e9b0ea1f0e2d6567ec75
and please let me know if I can further clarify

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I read the article. It's great! However, as far as I understand it, if every repair is based on a token range, the repair will only calculate merkle trees for the nodes holding replicas for that token range? That is, the answer is always "it does not".

Under what circumstance will a repair check if any other non-replica-nodes happen to have data they are not supposed to hold?

Comment: Non-replica nodes for a token range will never be involved in merkle-tree calculation for that range. This is probably inconvenient for your three node example, but think about the implications of running repairs in clusters with hundreds of nodes.

Comment: ...yeah, I guess the implications would be rather serious unless each node could keep track of non-associated data to quickly check for it (which based on your answer doesn't seem to be the case). Good point! Many thanks for your input! Much appreciated.